# How does Windows 10 determine if a driver update should cause restart?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, firmware

I am using Windows 10. In my `Device Manager`, I have several `Device Firmware` listed under the `Firmware` node.

I created a dummy device firmware driver for them.

Then I assign the dummy driver a version number, say, 0.0.0.1.
Then I use it to update one of my firmware devices. The system prompt me for a restart.

After I reboot into Windows, I can see my driver is working and the driver version is 0.0.0.1.

Then I assign the same dummy driver a higher version number, say, 0.0.0.2. And re-update the firmware device.

But this time, system doesn't prompt me to restart.

And I tried to down-grade to 0.0.0.1. Still no restart.

And in the event log -> System, I see something like this:

> Driver Management concluded the process to install driver ... with the
>   following status: 0x0.

And

> Device ... was configured.
>
> Outranked Drivers: ...

As I switch the drivers, they just keep ***outranking*** each other without any restart.

I am not sure what the `outrank` means here. I expected that each time I **change** the driver version, a restart should be required.

So why no restart?

Answer (score 1):

A restart would only be required if a file required by the driver is open and locked and cannot be replaced because it is currently in use and not able to be released by whatever software is using it.

If the device can be shutdown and unloaded without needing programs to release whatever locks they have on the device then there is no reason to reboot. It can simply unload the current driver, replace it with a new one, and then load the new driver.

The device driver is assumed to be able to fully initialize the device it drives from whatever random state it might be in after a reboot or system hibernate or power cycle. Unless a full power cycle is done the device will be in a nearly identical state after a reboot as a driver unload so the work that needs to happen would be the same.

Comment: Thanks. But in my scenario, I am updating a firmware device. The new firmware should be written into the flash. Can Windows 10 write to a flash without reboot?